# How to find the initial and the future population based on today's data?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help for the part B of the following questions. Here is the question and my work:

A certain species of bird was introduced in a certain county $25$ years ago. Biologists observe that the population doubles every $10$ years, and now the population is $27,000$.

$(A)$ - What was the initial size of the bird population? (Round your answer to the nearest whole number.)

$n\ \text{(initial)} = \dfrac{27,000}{2^{(25/10)}}\implies [n]\ \text{(initial)} = 4773$ ----- correct.

$(B)$ - Estimate the bird population $8$ years from now. (Round your answer to the nearest whole number.)

$n\ \text{(8 years later)} = 4773\times 2^{(8/10)}\implies [n]\ \text{(8 years later)} = 8310$ ----- wrong.

Comment: The population is now $27,000$. Therefore the population in eight years is $27,000\cdot 2^{\frac{8}{10} }$

Comment: Would it be 47010?

Comment: Yes. That is what I got.

Comment: If you use the initial value of the population, you would substitute $25 + 8 = 33$ for the time since $25$ years have already elapsed.  You would calculate $n(33) = 4773 \cdot 2^{\frac{33}{10}}$ to find the population eight years from now.

Answer (score 0):

Population is now 27000.
Before 10 yrs,it was 27000/2,
before 20 yrs it was $27000/2^2$,
before 25 yrs it was $27000/2^\frac{5}{2}=27000/4\sqrt2=4772$
Population after 8 yrs from now=$27000\times2^\frac{8}{10}=47009$